# How to get content-length for gZip enable file with HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, gzip

Some header parameters should be help to detect correct content length.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Get download file size returned from http server header. */
public static long getDownloadUrlFileSize(String downloadUrl) {
    long ret = 0;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try {
        if (downloadUrl != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(downloadUrl)) {
            URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity;q=1, *;q=0");
            System.out.println("Length : " + con.getContentLength());
            ret = con.getContentLength();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } finally {
        if (con != null)
            con.disconnect();
        return ret;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question ?